# How do I add my html navbar into another html file in django

Tags: django, django-templates, navbar

I am still very new to Django and I want to add the HTML for a navigation bar and its respective CSS into my base HTML file. Here is what I did up till now:

in app/base.html:

```
{% extends "BritIntlSchl/navbar.html" %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page title</title>
    <link href="{% static 'appname\stylebase.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="{% static 'appname\navbarstyles.css'}" rel="stylesheet" %}">  
    {% block head-content %}{% endblock head-content %}
</head>
    {% block nav%}{% endblock nav %}
    {% block content1 %}{% endblock content1 %}
</body>
</html>
```

and in app/navbar.html:

```
{% block nav%}    
<div class="wrap">...</div>
{% endblock nav%}
```

I am pretty much lost here. I am sure that putting{% block nav%} around the nav bar does nothing.
How do you suggest I go about this?

I'm using Django 2.1.

Answer (score 3):

When one uses the `extend` template tag one cannot have any HTML outside any block as then there would be the confusion of where to put this HTML (In fact the template engine would completely ignore that HTML). So when you extend `/navbar.html` at most you can fill the block named `nav` which you are overriding and filling with nothing. What you want to do is to use the [`include` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) to include the navbar into `base.html`:

#### base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page title</title>
    <link href="{% static 'appname\stylebase.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="{% static 'appname\navbarstyles.css'}" rel="stylesheet" %}">  
    {% block head-content %}{% endblock head-content %}
</head>
    {% block nav %}{% include 'app/navbar.html' %}{% endblock nav %}
    {% block content1 %}{% endblock content1 %}
</body>
</html>
```

> **Note**: We put the `{% block nav %}` there not because `navbar.html` would fill it but because some page extending `base.html` might want a
> custom navbar.

#### navbar.html:

```
<div class="wrap">...</div>
```